# Change payment context selected payment method

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments

Is it possible to change the `selectedPaymentMethod` without using Stripe's default change/add payment view controller? I tried doing `paymentContext.selectedPaymentMethod = ...` but after digging into Stripe's source code I saw that `selectedPaymentMethod` is get-only property.

`var paymentContext = STPPaymentContext`

Comment: Any luck with this? I' would like to achieve the same.

Comment: Same issues. Can change selectedPaymentMethod without using Stripe's default change/add payment view controller.

Comment: Was this ever answered?  I am having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still having this issue the solution I found was calling:

```
retryLoading()
```

just after setting the defaultPaymentMethod.

My method looks like:

```
func setDefaultPaymentMethod(id: String?) {
    paymentContext.defaultPaymentMethod = id
    paymentContext.retryLoading()
}
```